# How to convert an object to a 2 dimension branched string array

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, type-conversion

I have a 2 dimension branched array. This I converted to an object and write it via a serializer to a file. (The conversion to an object cause of the serializer, u know)
Now I read this file and have the object back - but how I am able to convert the object back to the 2d-branched array?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
// read object
SerializedObjectRead sr = new SerializedObjectRead();
sr.FileStreamName = @"E:\LOG\test.bin";
int intSuccesfullR = sr.Reader();
object back = new object();
if (intSuccesfullR == 0)
{
back = sr.ReadObj;
}

// here i want to convert the object to the 2d array


// my reader class
public class SerializedObjectRead
{
public string FileStreamName;
public object ReadObj;

public int Reader()
{
int intSuccesfull = 0;
try
{
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream(FileStreamName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
ReadObj = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
}
catch
{
intSuccesfull = -1;
}

return intSuccesfull;
}
}
```

Comment: Show us the code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast objects to a desired type.

```
object b;
example[,] r = (example[,])b;
```